# cannot execute the JS inside a popup window

Tags: javascript, html

http://jsfiddle.net/yuyhero/6FKVM/6/

I've made a simple demo that the parent webpage can get the value from its popup window. You can press 1.Popup window then press the 2. Get value to do that.

The situation is that I would like the button inside the popup window to get the value which is not working right now.

```
alert(document.getElementById(' + 'userInput' + ').value
```

The above script from the popup window doesn't work where Chrome debugger says cannot read property 'value' of NULL.

But If I change it to simply alert("hi") it works fine.

What I want is that eventually I can make it working and replace it with the already existing function merge().

Can anyone solve it? Much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear. Please tell what do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing double quotes in the id selector.

```
 s='<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">function set(){
     alert(document.getElementById("' + 'userInput' + '").value);
 }</sc'+'ript>';
```

Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/6FKVM/7/